# ajax autocomplete performance issues to hit the db or filter the pre-cahced results

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

In my existing asp.net application, i have a ajax autocomplete control, which uses a web method to get the autocomplete results which intern hits a stored procedure. But since hitting the db every time is costly and a performance issue, we wanted to cache all the lookup results which is around 45,000 rows and use the cahced data to filter out and get the data.

we are using linq query to filter by using contains method to check the prefix. But if i use the cached data filtering, it takes much longer than the original implementation which hits db everytime.

Is there any approach you can suggest me, which can give a much quicker result set retrieval when the user types the data in the UI.

I know that maintaining 45k no.of rows and filtering that would be a real pain. Hitting the db would be much more better approach.

Since we are facing some performance issues, please let me know any better approach.

Replacement of Ajax autocomplete with Jquery autocomplete plugin makes any difference..?

Code:
Just like any other ajax autocomplete code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
    runat="server" 
    ID="autoComplete1" 
    TargetControlID="myTextBox"
    ServiceMethod="GetUserList"></ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetUserList(string prefix)
{
return UserManager.GetUserNamesBySearch(prefix);
}

public string[] GetUserNamesBySearch(string prefix)
{
List<User> userCollection=UserServiceMgr.GetUserList(prefix);
var filteredUsers=from user in userCollection
              Where user.FirstName.contain(prefix)
              select user.FirstName.
filterdUsers.ToArray(); 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Suri

Comment: updated the code... the code is just like any other simple autocomplete plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, 45k+ records is too much to try and create a cache strategy.

Given that the "cache key" is a partial string, you will end up with duplicate results in the cache which you have to deal with.

We also use auto complete (jQuery) in our ASP.NET MVC application, and we have millions of records in the db.

We use a stored procedure, with **Full Text Search** over indexes views in the backend.

And given the amount of data, it performs reasonably well.

So i would suggest using a FTS provider such as SQL Server or Lucene to optimize your backend, not the use of ASP.NET cache.

FTS is a natural fit for auto complete, since it has built in smarts for things like noise words and thesauruses.

Comment: I think that you might have misunderstood my recommendation.  I wasn't recommending maintaining 45k individual values in the cache, I was recommending maintaining the object that holds those values.  For example retrieve the values once and cache them in whatever collection type is most useful for storage, searching, and ordering.  Again, if the underlying data is going to change often, you wouldn't want to cache at all and you would definitely want to optimize database access.  360k isn't much memory storage (45k * (assuming)8b average for a name).  He only needs names, not the whole record.

Comment: @GunnerL3510, true - but my main recommendation is that auto complete should be served by a FTS provider. LINQ `.Contains` is not robust enough to handle auto complete (e.g noise words, abbreviations, thesaurus, etc).

Comment: I posted the comment without seeing your response, so I've revised it...  I agree with you that when accessing the data at the database your method is absolutely recommended.  However, a combination of the best of both worlds might be appropriate as well.  Edit again...  I agree that LINQ is not optimal in this situation and FTS is much better suited to resolving the matching set.  However, I would argue that the overhead of accessing the database might exceed the overhead of LINQ.  I think in this case only testing would tell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, could you please let me know is there any implication, if i use FTS on my table. Is there any standard that if the table has these many rows and then only we have to use FTS..? please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @suresh - no, there is no implication, apart from when rows are added/updated/deleted, the FTS catalogue needs to be updated. Think of it like a "smart indexed view". If your using SQL Server, just do some testing. Create a FTS catalogue, access it via a SPROC, call that sproc from your AJAX, see how long it all takes. If it's still too slow - **then** consider caching. However as i said, we serve millions of records in an auto complete (location search), and it performs fine with no caching.

Answer (score 0):

If your underlying data source isn't going to change very often you can consider storing the results in the application's Cache and establish a timeout to refresh the data.  If the data changes every so often, you can set dependencies on the source table so that when the table's data gets modified it invalidates the cached object and then rebuilds the cached object.  If the data changes often then I would recommend doing exactly what you're doing now.

When I say "rebuild" the cached object, it is your application's responsibility to test for the presence of the cached object and rebuild it and reestablish it in the cache if is not present.

Keep in mind that if you will use an SqlDependency then you must set the database up for it.  aspnet_regsql.exe has the ability to set up your database.  Also, if your application relies on the fact that your data is guaranteed to be accurate then I would also do what you're doing now, or use SqlDependency.

[Caching Example](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/caching/object-caching/)

[SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx)

[aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)